# How to re-center an image once it has been dragged and zoomed in or out

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, zooming, panning

I am trying to create a class which handles zooming and panning components. The class contains references to an Anchorpane, which I am using since it does not do any aligning by default, as well as an ImageView which I want to be able to drag and zoom onto. The zooming and panning both work individually, but I am having trouble re-centering the image once it has been zoomed in or out.

The idea is that I want to be able to recenter the image when the app resizes so that dragging always appears to be relative to the center of the Anchorpane. By default any displacement in an Anchorpane is relative to the top-left corner, but that is not intuitive to the user. It would be much more logical for the content to appear to be moving relative to the center. To achieve this, the idea is to recenter the content whenever the window changes size, and then apply a translation corresponding to the amount of dragging done by the user

If you run the code I posted and zoom in, then resize the window, you'll notice that the red rectangle representing the image goes all over the place. If you shrink the window, then the square will no longer be at the same place as before. This only happens when scaling has been applied and appear to be a problem with the re-centering method.

If the centering method worked correctly, the square should return to the same position is was at before the window was expanded, which happens when the square is at 1 to 1 scale and no zooming has occured

Here is the class I use to handle the zoom and dragging

```java
package com.example.test;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.transform.Scale;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;

public class ZoomController{

    // the plane on which the node is being dragged
    private final AnchorPane PLANE;
    // the node I want to zoom and drag
    private final Node CONTENT;

    private Point2D lastContentPosition = new Point2D(0, 0);
    private Point2D lastMousePosition   = new Point2D(0, 0);
    // the total amount of dragging 
    // applied to the CONTENT node
    private Point2D dragOffset          = new Point2D(0, 0);

    // the total amount of scaling
    // applied to the CONTENT node
    private int scale = 1;

    public ZoomController(
            AnchorPane plane,
            Node content
    ) {
        this.PLANE = plane;
        this.CONTENT = content;

        addListeners();
        
        // artificially reproduces the problem
        applyZoom(2, new Point2D(0, 350));
        applyDrag(new Point2D(-100, 0));
    }

    private void addListeners() {
        // tries to center the CONTENT whenever the window is resized
        PLANE.heightProperty().addListener(centerContent());
        PLANE.widthProperty().addListener(centerContent());

        // saves the mouse's position whenever the mouse moves
        PLANE.setOnMousePressed(getMousePosition());
        PLANE.setOnMouseDragged(drag());

        PLANE.setOnScroll(handleScroll());
    }

    private ChangeListener<Number> centerContent() {
        return (observableValue, number, t1) -> {
            centerView();
        };
    }

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> drag() {
        return mouseEvent -> {

            // calculates the path taken by the mouse...
            Point2D newMousePosition = new Point2D(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY());
            Point2D mouseTranslation = lastMousePosition.subtract(newMousePosition);
            // ...and saves its new position
            updateMousePosition(mouseEvent);

            // applies the drag
            applyDrag(mouseTranslation);

        };
    }

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> getMousePosition() {
        return this::updateMousePosition;
    }

    private EventHandler<ScrollEvent> handleScroll() {
        return scrollEvent -> {

            // filters out the mouse stopping to scroll
            if (scrollEvent.getDeltaX() == 0 && scrollEvent.getDeltaY() == 0) return;

            // starts zooming
            if (scrollEvent.isControlDown()) {
                zoom(scrollEvent);
            }

        };
    }

    private void zoom(ScrollEvent scrollEvent) {

        // adds or subtracts to the image's scale based on
        // whether user is scrolling backwards or forwards
        final double dScale = scrollEvent.getDeltaY() > 0 ? 0.1 : -0.1;
        scale += dScale;

        // gets the coordinates IN THE IMAGE's FRAME OF REFERENCE
        // of the point at which to zoom the image so it is centered on the mouse
        Point2D target = CONTENT.parentToLocal(new Point2D(scrollEvent.getX(), scrollEvent.getY()));

        // applies the zoom to the image
        applyZoom(1 + dScale, target);

        // saves the image's position once it has been zoomed
        updateContentPosition();
    }

    private void applyZoom(final double zoomAmount, Point2D target) {
        // applies the necessary scaling to the image...
        Scale zoom = new Scale(zoomAmount, zoomAmount);
        // ...and centers the scaling to the point where the mouse is located at
        zoom.setPivotY(target.getY());
        zoom.setPivotX(target.getX());
        CONTENT.getTransforms().add(zoom);

        updateContentPosition();
    }

    private void applyDrag(Point2D dragAmount) {
        // drag amount always corresponds to the mouse's displacement
        // for the moment this is a 1 to 1 mapping
        // since I have not figured out how to take the scale into consideration

        // updates the total displacement caused by drag (used when we re-center the image)
        dragOffset = dragOffset.subtract(dragAmount);

        // applies the necessary translation to the image...
        Translate drag = new Translate();
        // ...based on the mouse's movement
        drag.setX(-dragAmount.getX());
        drag.setY(-dragAmount.getY());
        CONTENT.getTransforms().add(drag);

        // saves the image's position after it has been dragged
        updateContentPosition();
    }

    private void centerView() {
        // gets the coordinates we need to place the image at for it to be centered
        Point2D centerPosition = getCenterEdge();
        // calculates the path to take from the image's current position
        // to the position it has to be at to be centered
        // ie: the displacement vector
        Point2D translation    = centerPosition.subtract(lastContentPosition);

        // applies the necessary translation to the image...
        Translate translateToCenter = new Translate();
        // ...while account for drag so image is not fully re-centered
        translateToCenter.setX(translation.getX() + dragOffset.getX());
        translateToCenter.setY(translation.getY() + dragOffset.getY());
        CONTENT.getTransforms().add(translateToCenter);

        // saves the image's position after it has been centered
        updateContentPosition();
    }

    private void updateMousePosition(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        lastMousePosition = new Point2D(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY());
    }

    private void updateContentPosition() {
        // updates the image's position
        lastContentPosition = getContentPosition();
    }

    private Point2D getContentPosition() {
        // gets the minimal coordinates of the bounds around the image
        // ie: the image's coordinates
        Bounds contentBounds = CONTENT.getBoundsInParent();
        return new Point2D(contentBounds.getMinX(), contentBounds.getMinY());
    }

    private Point2D getCenterEdge() {
        // gets the size of the image and the anchor pane it is in...
        Point2D contentSize    = getContentSize();
        Point2D availableSpace = getAvailableSpace();
        // ...to determine the coordinates at which to place the image for it to be centerd
        return new Point2D(
                (availableSpace.getX() - contentSize.getX()) / 2,
                (availableSpace.getY() - contentSize.getY()) / 2
        );
    }

    private Point2D getContentSize() {
        // gets the bounds around the image
        Bounds contentBounds = CONTENT.getBoundsInParent();
        return new Point2D(contentBounds.getWidth(), contentBounds.getHeight());
    }

    private Point2D getAvailableSpace() {
        // gets the size of the Anchorpane the image is inn
        return new Point2D(PLANE.getWidth(), PLANE.getHeight());
    }


}
```

And here is the main class I am using to test the zoom

```java
package com.example.test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ZoomMain extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        // the node we want to drag & zoom
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(200, 100);
        rectangle.setFill(Color.RED);

        // the plane on which the node is being dragged
        AnchorPane plane    = new AnchorPane();

        // adds the node
        Scene mainScene = new Scene(plane);
        plane.getChildren().add(rectangle);

        // handles the zoom
        ZoomController zoomController = new ZoomController(
            plane,
            rectangle
        );

        stage.setTitle("Zooming test");
        stage.setScene(mainScene);
        stage.setMinHeight(500);
        stage.setMinWidth(500);

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

I have already tried to group the image to drag & zoom into a group, which would be useful since it would let me include multiple nodes to be dragged at once, however when I do that the contents of the group remain invisible.

Comment: Can you provide all the code as a single [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that it will be easy for others to directly focus on the issue.

Comment: @SaiDandem thanks for the tip, did my best to clarify the example and make it runnable

Comment: Well done. Please adhere to [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of re-centering the content after scale, use the center point of the content as the scale pivot.
In other words, scale around the center of the content.
Introduce a simple method to calculate the center:

```
private Point2D getContentCenter() {
    Bounds contentBounds = CONTENT.getBoundsInLocal();
    return new Point2D(contentBounds.getCenterX(), contentBounds.getCenterY());
}
```

And scale around it:

```
private void zoom(ScrollEvent scrollEvent) {
    // adds or subtracts to the image's scale based on
    // whether user is scrolling backwards or forwards
    final double dScale = scrollEvent.getDeltaY() > 0 ? 0.1 : -0.1;
    scale += dScale;
    Point2D target  = getContentCenter();
    // applies the zoom to the image
    applyZoom(1 + dScale, target);
}
```

EDIT:
The following `ZoomController` implements scaling around mouth positions and recentering of the content when the pane is resized :

```
class ZoomController{

    // the plane on which the node is being dragged
    private final AnchorPane PLANE;
    // the node I want to zoom and drag
    private final Node CONTENT;

    // the total amount of scaling  applied to the CONTENT node
    private int scale = 1;

    private Point2D lastMousePosition   = new Point2D(0, 0);

    public ZoomController( AnchorPane plane, Node content ) {
        PLANE = plane;
        CONTENT = content;

        PLANE.heightProperty().addListener((obs, number, t1) -> centerView());
        PLANE.widthProperty().addListener((obs, number, t1) -> centerView());

        // saves the mouse's position whenever the mouse moves
        PLANE.setOnMousePressed(event -> updateMousePosition(event));
        PLANE.setOnMouseDragged(drag());

        PLANE.setOnScroll(handleScroll());
    }

    private void updateMousePosition(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        lastMousePosition = new Point2D(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY());
    }

    private EventHandler<ScrollEvent> handleScroll() {
        return scrollEvent -> {
            // filters out the mouse stopping to scroll
            if (scrollEvent.getDeltaX() == 0 && scrollEvent.getDeltaY() == 0) return;
            // starts zooming
            if (scrollEvent.isControlDown()) {
                zoom(scrollEvent);
            }
        };
    }

    private void zoom(ScrollEvent scrollEvent) {

        // adds or subtracts to the image's scale based on
        // whether user is scrolling backwards or forwards
        final double dScale = scrollEvent.getDeltaY() > 0 ? 0.1 : -0.1;
        scale += dScale;

        // scale around mouse position
        Point2D pivot = CONTENT.parentToLocal(new Point2D(scrollEvent.getX(), scrollEvent.getY()));

        //applies the zoom to the image
        applyZoom(1 + dScale, pivot);
    }

    private void applyZoom(final double zoomAmount, Point2D target) {
        // applies the necessary scaling to the image...
        Scale zoom = new Scale(zoomAmount, zoomAmount);
        // ...and centers the scaling to the point where the mouse is located at
        zoom.setPivotY(target.getY());
        zoom.setPivotX(target.getX());
        CONTENT.getTransforms().add(zoom);
    }

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> drag() {
        return mouseEvent -> {

            // calculates the path taken by the mouse...
            Point2D newMousePosition = new Point2D(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY());
            Point2D mouseTranslation = lastMousePosition.subtract(newMousePosition);
            // ...and saves its new position
            updateMousePosition(mouseEvent);

            // applies the drag
            applyDrag(mouseTranslation);
        };
    }

    private void applyDrag(Point2D dragAmount) {
        // applies the necessary translation to the image...
        Translate drag = new Translate();
        // ...based on the mouse's movement
        drag.setX(-dragAmount.getX());
        drag.setY(-dragAmount.getY());
        CONTENT.getTransforms().add(drag);
    }

    private void centerView() {

        // gets the coordinates we need to place the image at for it to be centered
        Point2D centerPosition = CONTENT.parentToLocal(getCenterEdge());
        Point2D position = getContentPosition();

        Point2D translation    = centerPosition.subtract(position);
        // applies the necessary translation to the image...
        Translate translateToCenter = new Translate();
        translateToCenter.setX(translation.getX());
        translateToCenter.setY(translation.getY());
        CONTENT.getTransforms().add(translateToCenter);
    }

    private Point2D getContentPosition() {
        // gets the minimal coordinates of the bounds around the image
        // ie: the image's coordinates
        Bounds contentBounds = CONTENT.getBoundsInLocal();
        return new Point2D(contentBounds.getMinX(), contentBounds.getMinY());
    }

    private Point2D getCenterEdge() {
        // gets the size of the image and the anchor pane it is in...
        Point2D contentSize  = getContentSize();
        Point2D parentSize = getParentSize();
        // ...to determine the coordinates at which to place the image for it to be centered
        return new Point2D(
                (parentSize.getX() - contentSize.getX()) / 2,
                (parentSize.getY() - contentSize.getY()) / 2
        );
    }

    private Point2D getContentSize() {
        //BoundsInParent: rectangular bounds of this Node which include its transforms
        Bounds contentBounds = CONTENT.getBoundsInParent();
        return new Point2D(contentBounds.getWidth(), contentBounds.getHeight());
    }

    private Point2D getParentSize() {//renamed from getAvailableSpace()
        // gets the size of the Anchorpane the image is inn
        return new Point2D(PLANE.getWidth(), PLANE.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not what I ma looking for. I still want to be able to scale onto the point where the cursor is. All I am trying to do is to be able to recenter the image once it has been scaled, as right now that is not working. Individual components such as zooming and panning work on their own.

Comment: _recenter the image once it has been scaled_ it is not clear to me what is the benefit of zooming + recentring compared to zooming around the center

Comment: I am sorry, I mean recentering around the plane the image is in. I am also dragging the image along, and I want to be able to recenter the image once it has been zoomed in AND dragged. Right now that is the problem, since event though drag and zoom work, when combined I can no longer re-center the image.

Comment: I am aware that you are dragging and zooming. What I proposed does not contradict it. Did u try it  ? Zooming around the node center will not affect the drag. I am sorry but I still do not understand what do you mean by re-centering. From what I do understand is that zooming around the node's center eliminates the need to re-center.

Comment: Yep, I did try it. The problem is I would like to be able to re-center the image on the user's demand (or generally when needed) but I still want to be able to zoom to where the cursor is pointed, not just the middle of the image. If you run the code I posted and zoom in, then resize the window, you'll notice that the red rectangle representing the image goes all over the place. If you shrink the window, then the square will no longer be at the same place as before. This only happens when scaling has been applied and appear to be a problem with the re-centering method.

Comment: If the centering method worked correctly, the square should return to the same position is was at before the window was expanded, which happens when the square is at 1 to 1 scale and no zooming has occured

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem by setting a fixed scale and drag in the MRE ? It may be simpler to explain the required behavior and to troubleshoot.

Comment: Ok, I've gone ahead and done just that. Now content in the example is automatically zoomed in and dragged which should more clearly showcase the bug

Comment: Do you see the bug using this [ZoomController](https://ideone.com/bOfnoY) ? The idea is to make an **M**RE.  I find MRE very useful techniques. Not only it makes helping much easier, but it is also a powerful debugging tool. While preparing one, you are likely to find the problem or at least be able to pinpoint it.

Comment: Yep I do. It might be subtle since the rectangle isn't too zoomed in, but you'll notice that if you maximize the screen the rectangle will switch sides compared to the middle of the window. IE: before maximizing the rectangle is more to the right of the screen and after maximizing it is more to the left. If centering worked the rectangle should still be to the right of the screen;

Comment: The "bug" is clear. The desired behavior:_ If centering worked the rectangle should still be to the right of the screen_ isn't. Didn't you want to center the rectangle on the screen ?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. By default any displacement inside of the Anchorpane is relative to the top left corner. However, that is not very intuitive for the user, and it would be more logical to have the content kept in the center. So the idea is to have any displacement APPEAR as relative to the center of the Anchorpane, instead of the top left corner.

Comment: In the full app the idea is to keep track of the displacement applied to the rectangle / image: IE by how much the user has moved it since the start. If that was all then the content would appear to be dragged relative to the top left corner. To make it appear as if dragged from the center, I first center the content, then apply the translation. In that way any dragging appears to be relative to the center

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of clarity, I clearly should have posted a version of the code that was much closer to the actual app. In any case, regardless of any dragging, if the content was to be re-centered, which happens when the window changes size, then the rectangle representing the content should not be located to the left of the screen, but dead in the center. That is what I don't understand, why does the translation (which is supposed to recenter the content) not seem to work ?

Comment: Please keep in mind that the idea is not to center the content all the time, but only when the app resizes or the user requires it. This is done so that any dragging appears relative to the center

Comment: Please test the new `ZoomController` I posted

Comment: Yes that works perfectly, thank you very much for your help ! If I understand correctly, the main problem was that I was mistaken between local and parent coordinates is that it ? Thank you very much for your patience !